# R - write.xlsx could not find function

Tags: r, function

Hi guys I have some simple R code which is working on colleague computer but not on mine.

We use:

```
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
library(lubridate)
```

I installed all those packages but when I call function `write.xlsx()` I have an error:

```
could not find function "write.xlsx"
```

It is strange because the same code is working on colleague computer.
I installed those packages well on 100%. Is someone knows why it is not working on mine?

Thanks.

Best regards.

Comment: run `xlsx::write.xlsx` in console please

Comment: Error: in function loadNameSpace() for package 'rJava'
wywolanie: fun(libname, pkgname)
JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: Please provide the error message to your post. It's necessary information of this issue.

Comment: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx':
.onLoad nie powiodlo sie w funkcji 'loadNamespace()' dla pakietu 'rJava'
, szczegóły:
wywolanie: fun(libname, pkgname)
błąd: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
In addiction: warning message: 
pakiet 'xlsx' was built in version R 3.6.3

Comment: @Karollo it looks like you don't have Java installed. Either install Java or consider using a different package like `openxlsx` that doesn't require Java